# How to redirect login plus previous URL in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.1

```
                                        Laravel 5.1
```

I'm trying to build this functionality for every method in my controller. And this is very unpractical to do and very difficult to maintain. How can I set this that is when I registered an `auth` middleware in a specific route then it will redirect into a login page together with the URL that trying to view/visit.

**Example**:
URL: `public/users`

If this URL will try to visit by an unauthenticated user, then the user will be redirected to a url like `public/login?url=http://localhost/myproject/public/users`

Then After the user loggedin successfully, the user then will be redirected into `http://localhost/myproject/public/users`

**What I have now:**  *(But I think not a good one to use)*

```
public function getLoginURL(){
    if(!Input::get('location-login')){
        // URL is not set, redirect user to home.
        return redirect('/');
    }

    if(auth()->check()){
        // User is logged in. Go the specified URL (depends on the middleware of the url (route))
        return redirect()->to(Input::get('location-login'));
    }

    if(!auth()->check()){
        // Redirect user to a login with the URL provided
        return view('pages::auth.login.url');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next method in middleware... no need to send the url

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::user()) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect('/login');
}
```

Comment: Then what will happen after the user login successfully?

Answer (score 0):

> #### Use this in your `AuthController`

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle an authentication attempt.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function authenticate()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
    }
}
```

`intended()` function will redirect you to your intended location.
Check the full detail here [Intended redirect](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#authenticating-users)